# Flask request reset password internal server error

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a problem sending a request for resetting my password in flask.
This is the code in **init**.py for setting the email environment

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,url_for,flash,redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
import os

app=Flask(__name__) #the name of the application package

app.config['SECRET_KEY']='88fe5c0981ba01f5b81bcdb8c12dad29'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///site.db' #creates database  in the pc location
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt=Bcrypt(app)
login_manager=LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view='login'
login_manager.login_message_category='info'
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'


app.config['MAIL_PORT']=587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']=True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']=os.environ.get('NotifyEmail')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']=os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
mail=Mail(app)

from flaskdrip import routes
```

After starting the server I get this error even though I set up the environment variables for NotifyEmail and EMAIL_PASS

```
    Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Comment: Could you provide complete traceback? From what you posted it's not obvious where the error could come from.

Comment: Run Flask in debug mode to see the full error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I debugged but there was no traceback.

It shows only this:

 FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 429-769-432
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)